# emulating PBEWITHMD5ANDDES encryption under .net from JAVA

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

I am trying to emulate same behaviour of Java in C#. But I am not getting desired result. Key generated by both is different.

**JAVA CODE**

```
        public static String generateDecryptedKey(String secretKey, String authKey)
    {
        String strDecryptedKey = "";
        byte[] salt = { (byte)0x09, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0xA1, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0xA3, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0xA9, (byte)0xA0 };
        int iterationCount = 10;
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        byte[] enc = Base64.decodeBase64(authKey.getBytes());
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(enc);
        strDecryptedKey = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
        return strDecryptedKey;
    }
```

**C# CODE**

```
        public static string generateDecryptedKey(string secretKey,string authKey)
    {
        string strDecryptedKey = string.Empty;
        byte[] salt = { (byte)0x09, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0xA1, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0xA3, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0xA9, (byte)0xA0 };
        int iterationCount = 10;
        PKCSKeyGenerator kp = new PKCSKeyGenerator();
        ICryptoTransform crypt = kp.Generate(secretKey, salt, iterationCount, 1);   
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authKey);     
        byte[] resultBytes = crypt.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        strDecryptedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes);  
        return strDecryptedKey;
    }
```

Result generated by both function upon same input is coming wrong. I am new to cryptography, please someone explain where I am doing wrong. Below is the link for class written by BobJanova that I am using in C# conversion.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16450/Emulating-PBEWithMD-AndDES-Encryption-under-NET

**NOTE:** I don't want to reveal my SALT value so I had changed to some value. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authKey);
```

instead of

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authKey);
```

and

```
strDecryptedKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
```

instead of

```
strDecryptedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes);
```

in C#.

Also, `authKey.getBytes()` in Java might lead to problems down the line. Always specify an encoding like `authKey.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Comment: thank you @artjom-b for reply. Glad someone at least tried.I was about to lose faith on stackoverflow. I have tried to do the same as you suggested but output is coming different. **JAVA:** 6a48467d40035c6056b39eb06c90938941a1a23f.    **.NET:** {q���7�t���X��(f�J)�P3*��o�7ǥd߱\�����7T�� �l

Comment: Sorry, without some example inputs, I can't help you further.